# Exposing multiple QImages with image provider from model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to show `QImage` in QML, probably with `Image`. Currently, I found something like `QQuickImageProvider`, which I implemented and tried to use, but with no success.

I have `QList` of my own objects (`Item`), which are passed trough subclass of `QAbstractListModel` to sublclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel`, that is context property to `QQuickView`. Every `Item` in `QList` contains `QImage` as an attribute. I tried to change `QImage` attribute to `ImageProvider`, but there is no way to add image provider to `QQuickView->engine` for every `Item`.

I tried to expose `ImageProvider` as `Item` attribute with `Q_PROPERTY`, but it was same result as direct referencing to `QImage`: `Unable to assign QImage to QUrl`

**Item.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include "ImageProvider.h"

class Item : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage getItemPhoto READ getItemPhoto WRITE setItemPhoto NOTIFY photoChanged)

public:
    // ---- PUBLIC METHODS ----
    //! Sets up unique ID for Item
    explicit Item();

    //! Returns image source path
    QImage getItemPhoto() const { return photo_; }

    //! Sets source path for the image of the Item
    void setItemPhoto(const QImage &imageSource);

signals:
    // ---- SIGNALS ----

    photoChanged();

private:
    // ---- PRIVATE METHODS ----
    //! Set id of Item
    void setId(const int &ID);

private:
    // ---- PRIVATE ATTRIBUTES ---

    QImage photo_;

    QImage heatMap_;
};
```

**ImageProvider.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>

class ImageProvider : public QObject, QQuickImageProvider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ImageProvider();

    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);

public slots:
    void setPhoto(const QImage &photo);

signals:
    void photoChanged();

private:
    QImage photo_;
};
```

**ImageProvider.cpp**

```
#include "ImageProvider.h"

ImageProvider::ImageProvider() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{
    this->blockSignals(false);
}

QImage ImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    Q_UNUSED(id)
    QImage res = this->photo_;

    if(res.isNull())
        return QImage();

    if(size)
    {
        *size = res.size();
    }

    if(requestedSize.width() > 0 && requestedSize.height() > 0)
        res = res.scaled(requestedSize.width(), requestedSize.height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio); //TODO

    return res;
}

void ImageProvider::setPhoto(const QImage &photo)
{
    if(photo_ != photo)
    {
        photo_ = photo;
        emit photoChanged();
    }
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
GridView {
    //.... 
    model:filterModel

    delegate: Image {
        id: item
        //....
        source: item.getItemPhoto //item is role name for Item
    }
}
```

As I said, I have tried to add `ImageProvider` instead of `QImage`. However, I don't know how to expose them as `QUrl`.

Anyone knows where problem is?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should not expose `QQuickImageProvider` to QML but register the provider using `QQmlEngine::addImageProvider` instead. To access specified image you have to provide some identifier to Image.source. List of images should be accessible to `QQuickImageProvider` internally. I guess that Qt provides clear and comprehensible example, just refer to the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to associate some id to the image, and pass the id to the QQuickImageProvider, in the requestImage method you have to obtain the image of the model using the id.

To do this you must create another role, in this example call uuid associated with a property at that value.

**item.h**

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <QImage>
#include <QObject>
#include <QUuid>

class Item : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage photo READ photo WRITE setPhoto NOTIFY photoChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QUuid uuid READ uuid NOTIFY uuidChanged) // <---id
public:
    using QObject::QObject;

    QImage photo() const {
        return mPhoto;
    }
    void setPhoto(const QImage &photo){
        mPhoto = photo;
        emit  photoChanged();
        mUuid = QUuid::createUuid();
        emit uuidChanged();
    }
    QUuid uuid() const {
        return mUuid;
    }
signals:
    void photoChanged();
    void uuidChanged();
private:
    QImage mPhoto;
    QUuid mUuid;
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

**itemmodel.h**

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
     Item *item =  mItems[index.row()];
    if(role == Qt::UserRole){
        return QVariant::fromValue(item);
    }
    else if(role == Qt::UserRole+1){
        return QVariant::fromValue(item->uuid());
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Qt::UserRole] = "item";
    roles[Qt::UserRole+1] = "uuid";
    return roles;
}
```

**modelimageprovider.h**

```
#ifndef MODELIMAGEPROVIDER_H
#define MODELIMAGEPROVIDER_H

#include "item.h"

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QUuid>

class ModelImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    explicit ModelImageProvider(QAbstractItemModel *model)
        :QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
    {
        mModel = model;
    }
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize){
        Q_UNUSED(requestedSize)
        Q_UNUSED(size)
        // search item
        QUuid uuid(QByteArray::fromPercentEncoding(id.toLatin1()));
        QModelIndexList indexes = mModel->match(
                    mModel->index(0, 0),
                    Qt::UserRole+1,
                    QVariant::fromValue(uuid),
                    1,
                    Qt::MatchRecursive);
        if(indexes.size() > 0){
            Item *it = qvariant_cast<Item *>(indexes[0].data(Qt::UserRole));
            if(it)
                return it->photo();
        }
        return QImage();
    }
private:
    QAbstractItemModel *mModel;
};

#endif // MODELIMAGEPROVIDER_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
...
ModelImageProvider *provider = new ModelImageProvider(manager.filterModel());
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImageProvider("model", provider);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("manager", &manager);
...
```

**main.qml**

```
...
delegate:
    Image {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source: "image://model/"+item.uuid
}
...
```

---

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51382435).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it returned image by id.

Answer (score 0):

Take all your images and make them accessible through one `ImageProvider`.

Usage in QML looks like:

```
Image { source: "image://myimageprovider/image05.png" }
```

To link the "myimageprovider" string that is used in URL, the provider must be registered like that:

```
QQmlEngine::addImageProvider("myimageprovider", imageProvider);
```

Your image provider has a member function:

```
virtual QImage ImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);
```

The "image05.png" string from the URL is passed there by Qt as that `const QString &id` parameter.